# Creating dynamic array in java without using collection

Tags: java, arrays

I was asked in interview: "how can I create a dynamic array without using any collection like ArrayList, vector, etc."

I said it is not possible because array is of fixed size. They said no it is possible you need to write a program to answer this.

I was unable to answer this question. They gave me one hint "use generics", even though it seems to be very difficult for me to answer this question. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Maybe they just wanted you to write your own implementation of `ArrayList`. Who knows, we certainly don't.

Comment: This is definitely possible. In fact, this is how Java's collections framework is doing it. The idea is to make a class that puts `List<T>` interface on top of an implementation that wraps a built-in, non-resizable, array. Look up source code of `ArrayList<T>` to see how it is done.

Answer (score 4):

The implementation of Collections uses similar concept. You need to define a generic array with default_size say n = 10(say), and default load_factor =0.75(say)

```
T[] array = (T[])new Object[DEFAULT_SIZE];
```

And a variable `index` to store the current position in array.

when `index > n*load_factor` create  new array of greater size and copy all elements into it and it will be your new Array, similarly when removing element `index < n*load_factor` (these criteria depends on many parameters, this is just example) reduce the size of array.

Partial sample code

```
public class CustomArrayList <T> {
  private int index = 0;
  private final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 10;
  private final double DEFAULT_LOAD = 0.75;
  private T[] array;

  public CustomArrayList(){
    array = (T[])new Object[DEFAULT_SIZE];
  }

  public void add(T elem){
    if(index>=array.length*DEFAULT_LOAD){
        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length+10);
    }
    array[index++]=elem;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to understand your answer. Can you please explain in detail or in simpler way.

Comment: What that code means is - create an array of T type(T can be replaced with Integer, Long etc) of size(10). Then create two variables say index and load_factor. With each iteration you will fill array index by index(so increase index variable value each time) And next check on each iteration that if the value of index variable got greater than n * load_factor.Here n * load_factor=0.75 means 3/4 of the array. It checks that if you have filled 3/4th of the array. Create new array of same type with new size added to previous array size. you are creating array dynamically without collections.

Comment: @100rabh I sometimes stay in a room where people are getting interviews for the company that I work and I find this answer a bit off. This is not about an actual solving of the problem, but a few hints in the correct direction, even if my understanding is that SO does not encourage this... Like this for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/48360890/1059372

Comment: @Eugene I could not get much of it other than you you are explaining it more from interview experiences (if I'm right) and the question is in that context...and your answer explains it more rather than code..

Answer (score 0):

What is a dynamic array in Java? Here is a conceptual example:
We want to store data in an array, but we don't know how large it will be. So when we want to insert and there is no space we need to find a larger block of memory and copy all the entries in that block. Now consider two ways of doing it.
**The bad way**
*We allocate a block of 1000 entries.*
*Every time there isn't enough space we allocate a new block with 100 more entries.*
**How much time will this take:**
To insert n entries, the number of copies will be 1000
×
k
+ 100
×
(1 + 2 +
. . .
+ (
k
−
1)) = 1000 k + 50k(k−1)
Therefore the time taken is quadratic in k and also in n.
**The good way**
*Allocate a block of 1000 entries and when there isn't enough space allocate a new block of twice the size.*
**How much time will this take**
 Total number of copies is: 1000
×
(1 + 2 + 4 +
···
+ 2^(
k
−
1)
) = 1000
×
(2^k
−
1)
<=
n
Total number of insertions is: 1000
×
(1 + 1 + 2 + 4 +
···
+ 2^(
k
−
1)
) = 1000
×
2^k=n
So the total time is linear in n and average time is constant.
Once you understand this concept you will be able to create a dynamic array in any language you know.

Answer (score 0):

I got some idea for your question. Dynamic array is something which changes it's size during the run time. I have completed twelfth grade just now, and I am sharing what came to my mind...

Program:

```
public class DynamicArr {//method to increase size dynamically during runtime

    public static int[] incrSize(int arr[]) {
        int len = arr.length;
        int newArr[] = new int[len+1]; //increasing the length of the current array in an other temporary array
        return newArr; // returning the new array

    }

    public static void main(String... strings) {
        int a[] = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Size Before Increase: " + a.length);
        a = incrSize(a); // pointing the reference to the new array by calling the incrSize() method
        System.out.println("Size After Increase: " + a.length);

    }

}
```

You can copy all the values in the current array into the temporary array and add the new value to the array that can extend the size of the array.
You can also extend the size as required.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

They basically wanted a few things to find out. Like how would you model a "Holder" for such an array, how would you make public `get(int index)` or `set(T value, int index)` or `size`.

"use generics" was a very good hint, as you should have at least started with:

```
Holder<T> {
   T[] array = (T[])new Object[10]; // 10 just as an example  
}
```

If you wrote this down, they could have further asked why not `T[] array = new T[10]` and you should have said that you can't create a generic array in java (you could have mentioned `@SafeVarArgs` here even). Further down you should have said that arrays are covariant and that the cast is allowed for arrays, but not for collections; also it would generate a compiler warning that you would need to suppress.

Later you could have added a method, like `add(T value)` and how would that get implemented. Here they would have expected for you to know what 
`Arrays.copyOfRange` or `System.arrayCopy` is and how that works.

They could have even asked why not add *all* subtypes of `T` and the proper syntax for that (`look for generics bounds`).

It would also require for you to may be think of how `delete` of an element would work on a specific index? Would you `null` it? Would you delete it? If so, how would you do that from an array? Would you shrink the size of the array when something gets deleted? (hint: java collections don't do that, unless you tell them to explicitly: `ArrayList#trimToSize()`)

When you inner array is full, and you want to add one more element, by how much would you expand it? `50%`, `75%`? Or just enough space for a single element? If you knew how jdk's internal collections work, the answer would be very simple.

I guess it's not a bad interview question at all IMO.